# What is the siglum for the Arabic Diatessaron?

Tags: textual-criticism

I have browsed the Internet quite a bit but could not find the scribal abbreviation for the Diatessaron (maybe an established siglum for it does not exist).

Comment: In what context are you asking?  In UBS5 the name is written out in full as "Diatessaron" in the critical apparatus. There is a version in Syriac and Armenian (there is also a Greek fragment).  Please ask a more specific question.  Translations into various languages also exist.

Comment: In what context?? If there is an established siglum I'd like to know it, - writing out "Diatessaron" takes a lot of space. Yes, I am aware of those versions, but I was asking how the Arabic Diatessaron is abbreviated. How much more specific can one get? Shall I add which Arabic recension??

Comment: Agreed, but that is what is done in UBS4 and UBS5 in their critical apparatus.

Comment: OK, thanks. Thus, it seems there is no established siglum.

Comment: 'siglum' - _a letter or symbol which stands for a word or name, especially to denote a particular manuscript or edition of a text_.